# Passing Dynamic Arrays (simple)

Tags: arrays, pointers

Sorry, this is probably a really easy fix but I just can't seem to get it to compile
The assignment requires me to use dynamic memory, and the code has to be written this way.
Basically I can't seem to be able to pass my array to a function.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

// Comment:
void count(int array[],int length,int& numneg,int& numpos);

// Comment:
void split();

// Comment:
void print_array();

int main(){

  int length(0),x(0),numpos(0),numneg(0);
  cout << "Enter number of elements: ";
  cin >> length;
  int *array = new int[length];
  cout << "Enter list:" << endl;
  cin >> x;
  for (int i(0);i<(length-1);i++)
    {
      array[i] = x;
      cin >> x;
    }
  count(array[length],length,numneg,numpos);





  delete [] array;
  return 0;
}

void count(int array[],int length,int& numneg, int& numpos)
{
  for (int i(0);i<(length-1);i++)
    {
      if (array[i] < 0)
    numneg++;
      else 
    numpos++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing an array or a pointer to a function, just use the name of the variable.

You call to `count` needs to be:

```
count(array,length,numneg,numpos);
```

By using `array[length]` you accessing the element of the point at the index of length, which would be an `int` not an `int*` not to mention being one element past the size of your buffer.